# Why won't my jQuery onChange event trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble with simple jquery. Here is my html.

```
 <label>Select User</label>
    <span class="field">
        <select name="selectUser" id="selectUser">
            <option value="">Choose One</option>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Users)
            {
                <option value="@item.Id">@item.UserName</option>
            }
        </select>
    </span>
```

Here is the script:

```
<script>
$('#selectUser').change( function() {    
    alert("hello");      
});
```

now when i change the options in the select element nothing happens?

[EDIT]

SelecUser was a typo, I fixed it and still No alert message.

Comment: Because the id is `selecUser` not `selectUser`.

Comment: You may have to select a different element before onchange will fire.

Answer (score 2):

Because your id is `selecUser` instead of `selectUser`

Try this

```
$('#selecUser').change(function() {    
    alert("hello");      
});
```

you can try this as well

```
$('#selecUser').on("change",function() {    
    alert("hello");      
});
```

Comment: Tried both and still nothing.

Comment: `option`s doesn't added dynamically, full `html` of `select` will be returned from ASP server

Comment: _"As you are dynamically adding the option"_. It's generated server-side, so there is no need to use event delegation, also that's not how you delegate the events using `on` method. It seems missing document ready handler is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

first of all You need to change the id for selector. also you either need to write that code in documnet ready or use jquery on.Use:

```
$(document).on('change','#selecUser',function() {    
 alert("hello");      
});
```

Comment: @Freak_Droid:where do you see that in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual `id` is `id="selecUser"`. Change it to `selectUser`